# How to retrieve a handle to facts inside a deffacts construct?

Tags: clips

As described by the question, I would somehow try to get an handle to a fact within a deffacts construct. The problem arises because I don't want to redefine the same thing several times in WM (since set-fact-duplication is true) and because I use a structured deftemplate in which a field is a FACT_ADDRESS.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind a fact address within a deffacts construct. What I would suggest instead is to use a symbolic link between the facts. In your case, if the name of the tourism-type, tourism-resort, and hotel facts is unique among facts of each type, you could use that slot as the symbolic link:

```
(deftemplate tourism-type
   (slot name)
   (slot score))

(deftemplate hotel
   (slot name)
   (slot tr)
   (slot stars)
   (slot price-per-night))

(deftemplate tourism-resort
   (slot name)
   (slot region)
   (multislot type))

(deffacts the-tourism-type-list
   (tourism-type (name culturale) (score 3))
   (tourism-type (name enogastronomico) (score 4)))

(deffacts the-tourism-resort-list
   (tourism-resort
      (name Venezia)
      (region Veneto)
      (type culturale enogastronomico)))

(deffacts the-hotels-list
   (hotel
      (name hotel1)
      (tr Venezia)
      (stars 3)
      (price-per-night 100)))
```

In your rules, you can then use the symbolic link to retrieve the linked fact:

```
(defrule food-and-wine-hotels
   (hotel (name ?hotel)
          (tr ?tr-name))
   (tourism-resort
      (name ?tr-name)
      (type $? enogastronomico $?))
   =>
   (printout t ?hotel crlf))
```